# keras stuck at 0 loss value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i'm doing [this kaggle contest](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia) where i have to classify this x-ray in 3 category bacteria,virus or normal. Problem is that my accuracy is really low like 25% and loss is stuck at 0. I use a pretrained nn using weight that come from a dataset of xray chest images. This nn use keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy as loss function and keras.metrics.Accuracy() for accuracy

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

TRAIN_DIR = 'D:/tf/archiveBilanciato/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA'
TEST_DIR = 'D:/tf/archiveBilanciato/chest_xray/test'
IMG_SIZE = 224  #224 è quella migliore
image_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)
batch_size = 32
LR = 1e-3

import os

nt = 0
for folder_name in ("bacteria", "normal","virus"):
    folder_path = os.path.join("D:/tf/NeoArchiveBilanciato/chest_xray", folder_name)
    for fname in os.listdir(folder_path):
        fpath = os.path.join(folder_path, fname)
        nt += 1
print("Totale immagini: %d" % nt)


train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "D:/tf/NeoArchiveBilanciato/chest_xray",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337,
    color_mode='rgb',
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "D:/tf/NeoArchiveBilanciato/chest_xray",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1337,
    color_mode='rgb',
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D,Dense

def pre_model():
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(
        weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    predictions = Dense(14, activation="softmax")(x)
    pre_model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

    return pre_model

base_model = pre_model()
base_model.load_weights("D:/tf/nih_pretrained_chest_model.h5")
#print(base_model.summary())


from keras.layers import Input
#from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from kerassurgeon.operations import delete_layer, insert_layer
from keras.models import load_model
new_input = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), name='image_input')
model_imp = base_model
model_imp = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(model_imp.layers[-2].output)



base_model.trainable = False
mio_classificatore = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(base_model.layers[-2].output)

nuovo_model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=mio_classificatore)

#print(nuovo_model.summary())

train = train_ds
val = val_ds


nuovo_model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

nuovo_model.fit(train,batch_size=32, epochs=14, validation_data=val)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot use softmax with one neuron, it would produce a constant output.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 categories to predict, so the last layer in your model should contain 3 neurons(1 for each class), not 1 neuron

Try to change

```
mio_classificatore = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(base_model.layers[-2].output)
```

to

```
mio_classificatore = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(base_model.layers[-2].output)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. When i do so I get this error: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible